# Can't insert into newly created MYSQL table immediately. "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist"

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want my code to create tables and insert to them immediately afterwards.

Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `randomtablename` (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

And immediately after:

```
INSERT INTO `randomtablename` (`id`) VALUES ('1')
```

I am 100% sure that both sql statements are correct.

When I take a look at my database from phpmyadmin, the newly created table doesnt show up on the left menu. When I refresh the page and list my tables by clicking on the database, I see the table on the right but still not on the left. Only after I click the table on the right that the left menu updates and shows the newly created table.

The sql statements above continuously produce the same error until I follow the steps I describe above. This leads me to think that there is some sort of a caching problem that prevents the database to acknowledge the existence of the newly created table. Only after I follow the steps above my code stops producing that error message.

How do I make mySQL recognize the existence of the newly created table immediately so that I can insert to it right after the creation?

Comment: If you are using `Mysql` then why are you tagging `Sql Server`

Comment: I'm sorry. I followed the suggested tags. Didn't know the two were unrelated. I'll untag it now. Do you know the answer?

Comment: Forget about phpmyadmin,use a modern client like http://www.heidisql.com/

Comment: sorry I don't have much idea in `Mysql`. Wait you will get answers

Comment: @JayBlanchard You can insert, if that is not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm not sure what role phpmyadmin plays here. Can you reproduce this using the plain-old `mysql` command-line tool? Generally if a table is created successfully it is available immediately. There is no delay.

Comment: _"I am 100% sure that both sql statements are correct."_ lol

Comment: Could you please paste the SQL executed statement reported by PHPMA?

Comment: I think there's a good question in here somewhere but you would have to form some concrete reproduction steps using the mysql command-line client, that we can follow.

Comment: This might help you out: http://forums.codewalkers.com/php-coding-7/create-table-and-insert-data-on-same-php-page-842568.html